# Visual C#: How to add controls to a form created with code?

Tags: c#

I'm new to Visual C# and I'm currently stuck on how to create a new form (with code, not design) and add things (namely labels and textboxes) to this new form. Here's what I have right now:

```
namespace AccountInfo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            profileForm profile = new profileForm();  // Make new form
            profile.Name = "newProfile";
            profile.Text = "Add a new profile";
            profile.LabelText = "test";
            profile.Show();             // Display form
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }

    public class profileForm : Form
    {
        // Controls
        Label label1 = new Label();

        public profileForm()
        {

        }

        public string LabelText
        {
            set { label1.Text = value; }
        }

        private void profileForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I get the default form and I click button1. It brings up a new form, but with nothing on it. I expect a label to show up but it won't. I've tried this multiple different ways (this being my most recent method) and I can't get anything to show up. I've looked around StackOverflow and one other topic came up, but its solution didn't work for me. I'd appreciate any insight into this :) Thanks a ton!

Edit: I've also tried this using the constructor instead. It didn't help.

Comment: Right Click `InitializeComponent();` and Goto Definition (or F12). There you will see the Form Designer generated code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a Label object in memory but you're not assigning it to a particular parent control, or setting it's position etc...  Google "Dynamically create controls C#" and you'll find a tonne of [examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984255%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

You basically need to call the following two lines from somewhere in profileForm.

```
   label1.Location = new Point(25,25);

   this.Controls.Add(label1);
```

Comment: Ahh, thanks. I was missing the Controls.Add line. I was tinkering with this earlier and couldn't figure out what it wanted me to say. The code I posted here is a bit...less...than what I was messing with before (So if it makes it look like I wasn't trying, that's not the case :) ). Thanks for the help!

Comment: Haha, thanks! New to StackOverflow as well...haven't discovered all of its intricacies yet :)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Dylan, you need to add the Label object to the profileForm in the load event as follows:

```
this.Controls.Add(label1);
```

Comment: Is there any reason to stick this in the load event rather than the constructor? It seems like there are several ways to accomplish this goal but I'm not sure which is the best, or why...

Comment: No reason to have it in the Load event. You can even add the control in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Soon, i was watching a video that answers to this question.
It is complete guide how to add dinamicly controlls with the flow layout.
Here is the video: http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=13245